# Leaflet 'Click' event on line portion

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, line

I have a polyline as GeoJSON layer in Leaflet.

I need a JavaScript event when the user click on the portion of the line.

I have to highlight the selected line segment. Is it possible this?

Comment: Are you looking for a similar behavior to this  https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ leaflet example?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the basic idea, set a style for the line, and set a style for the highlight, then in your forEachFeature function, set the layer on click to highlight. My example below resets the style in case, you clicked on one before.

```
var highlight = {
    'fillColor': 'yellow',
    'weight': 2,
    'opacity': 1
};

    function forEachFeature(feature, layer) {

        layer.on("click", function (e) { 
            stateLayer.setStyle(style); //resets layer colors
            layer.setStyle(highlight);  //highlights selected.
        }); 
    }
```

Here is a working example for a polygon layer.  http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/basic/basic_Poly.html